# Sort by text date

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

I have:
14/12 Text 1
23/12 Text 2
08/11 Text 3
08/10 Text 4
(European dates DD/MM)

I'd like to arrange this by date, but is in text format.
Desired output:
08/10 Text 4
08/11 Text 3
14/12 Text 1
23/12 Text 2

Comment: So you have text in the displayed format, and you want to sort it as if they were dates with DD/MM, right? In this case, would you be open to using [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) for this?

Comment: I wanted to keep it as clean as possible. I can pull the dates by themselves and concatenate it in the next step. Was just hoping there was a secret I didn't know about :)

Comment: So you'd want to sort it directly in the original list? Well, I don't think that's possible in plain Sheets. It could be done with Apps Script though, using an `onEdit` trigger. I understand you're not interested in that?

Comment: I'm trying to avoid scripts when it can be done in formulas, thanks!

Comment: Hi, I thought you wanted to sort the original list directly, but I see that's not the case, since you accepted the existing answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do it?  I assume you're talking about sorting a range like A2:A?
This formula sorts first by the month, then by the day.

```
=SORT(A2:A,MID(A2:A,4,2),1,1,1)
```

#### Reference:

- [SORT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093150?hl=en)
- [MID](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en)

Comment: This works great! I don't quite understand the ",1,1,1" at the end, what is this telling the function to do?

Comment: the first 1 is to tell it to sort ASCENDING based on the MID() array.  The next one tells it to sort next based on the *first* column.  And the final 1 is telling it to sort ASCENDING based on that *first* column.